# Problematic booting process

Tags: boot, shutdown, startup

About a month ago I installed `Lubuntu 11.10`. Since that time there is a problem with booting and shutting down.

1. Booting is endless. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwT1o.jpg) screen never disappears, so I have to manually press the shutdown button of my laptop
2. I turn the laptop on and have the possibility of [choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRpT.jpg). I choose the second option - `Linux 3.0.0-14-generic (recovery mode)`
3. I will [choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9MJP.jpg) `resume normal boot` option
4. [Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH8Ka.jpg)

Sometimes `Lubuntu` boots normally but in most cases I have to go through steps 1-4. When I shutdown the OS I will see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwT1o.jpg) screen forever, so I have to press my laptop button to turn it off.

Do you know where is the problem and how to solve it? I'm asking rather here (not in Ubuntu), because this is system problem what I'm interested in (not the matter of one distribution) but booting process and here are more experts interested in the system (what is under the hood).

thank you

Comment: Some (most?) shutdown screens can be stopped by pressing escape. Then you can see what userspace and the kernel say during shutdown. That may give you hints.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I cannot comment on the question, so I am forced to write it here. My apologies.

Edit /etc/default/grub and check GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, there is probably some 'quiet' and 'splash' options there. Remove them, run 'sudo update-grub' and reboot. You should now see some more information during the boot process, and maybe a hint what's going wrong.

Comment: I appreciate every answer. After reboot, grup command line appears and I have to type [manually](http://i.imgur.com/wGivm.jpg)

Comment: You probably did it wrong :) There should be no need for manually specifying what to boot. Anyway, are you seeing any error messages during boot?

Comment: I just comment the line in `/etc/default/grub`. During boot I haven't catched nothing, only when shutting down, but it's too fast to make a photo. It would be best to redirect the messages to a file, if it's possible.